# pandas 別のデータフレームから参照して置換する方法

Tags: python, pandas

プログラミング初学者です。
pandasでのデータフレームに関しての質問です。
2つのデータフレームで要素が一致したら置換する方法で苦戦しております。

[例]

```
[df1]
id, fruits
1, ringo
2, mikan
3, suika

[df2]
id, fruits_en, fruits_jp
1, apple, ringo
2, watermelon, suika
3, peach, momo
4, orange, mikan
```

[df2]を参照して、[df1]'fruits'を[df2]'fruits_en'要素へ置換したいのです。
以下、期待する結果

```
[df1]
id, fruits
1, apple
2, orange
3, watermelon
```

[試した方法]
`df.loc()`を用いた要素抽出から以下試みました。

```
df1.loc[df1['fruits'] == df2['fruits_jp'], 'fruits'] = df2['fruits_en']
```

結果、以下のようにエラーを返されてしまいました。

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

上記例のように、別のデータフレームの列要素に一致した場合に置換する方法をご教授いただけませんでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下は [pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) を使う方法です。

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
  'id': [1, 2, 3],
  'fruits': ['ringo', 'mikan', 'suika']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
  'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
  'fruits_en': ['apple', 'watermelon', 'peach', 'orange'],
  'fruits_jp': ['ringo', 'suika', 'momo', 'mikan']
})

df1.fruits = df1.fruits.map(df2.set_index('fruits_jp').fruits_en)

print(df1)

   id      fruits
0   1       apple
1   2      orange
2   3  watermelon
```

**追記**

> mapメソッドのほかにreplaceというものも見つけたのですが、明確な違いは何かありますでしょうか。

[pandas.Series.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) を使う場合は以下の様になります。

```
df1.fruits = df1.fruits.replace(df2.fruits_jp.to_list(), df2.fruits_en)
```

ここで、例えば `df2` の中身が以下の様になっているとします。

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
  'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  'fruits_en': ['apple', 'watermelon', 'peach', 'orange', 'delicious'],
  'fruits_jp': ['ringo', 'suika', 'momo', 'mikan', 'ringo']
})
```

`fruits_jp` の要素に重複(`ringo`)があり、`ringo` に対する `fruits_en` の要素は `apple` と `delicious` になっています。

```
>>> df1.fruits.replace(df2.fruits_jp.to_list(), df2.fruits_en)
0     delicious
1        orange
2    watermelon
```

`replace` の場合は最後の対応要素に置換されますが、`map` ではエラーになってしまいます。原因は `df2.set_index('fruits_jp')` としているためです。

```
>>> df1.fruits.map(df2.set_index('fruits_jp').fruits_en)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 3630, in map
    new_values = super()._map_values(arg, na_action=na_action)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 1121, in _map_values
    indexer = mapper.index.get_indexer(values)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2733, in get_indexer
    raise InvalidIndexError(
pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。上記方法にて解決しました。
mapメソッドのほかにreplaceというものも見つけたのですが、明確な違いは何かありますでしょうか。お時間ありましたらご返答お待ちしております。

Comment: なるほど、エラーを避けるために安易にreplaceを使うとデータが意図しない形になってしまう恐れもあるのですね。
お忙しい中分かりやすいご説明ありがとうございました。