# pandas リストデータフレームから参照して列を追加したい

Tags: python, pandas

先日、[pandas 別のデータフレームから参照して置換する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/66396/pandas-%e5%88%a5%e3%81%ae%e3%83%87%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%83%95%e3%83%ac%e3%83%bc%e3%83%a0%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e5%8f%82%e7%85%a7%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e7%bd%ae%e6%8f%9b%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95)を質問した者です。
上記は解決したのですが、下記のデータフレームで参照する方法が上手くいきません。
[例]
[df2]を参照して、'City'に対応するCityCodeを[df1]に追加したい

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['John', 'Milke', 'Saya', 'Taro'],
    'Residence': ['Osaka', 'Kyoto', 'Nagoya', 'Kyoto']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'City': ['Osaka', 'Kyoto', 'Fukuoka', 'Nagoya'],
    'CityId': [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004]
})
```

[求めたい結果]

```
[df1]
Name, Residence, CityId
John, Osaka, 1001
Mike, Kyoto, 1002
Saya, Nagoya, 1004
Taro, Kyoto, 1002
```

[試した方法]
mapメソッドのほかに、isinメソッドを試してみました。

```
#初めにdf1に'CityCode'を追加し0を代入しておく
df1['CityCode'] = 0

df1['CityCode'] = df2[df2['CityCode'].isin(df1['Residence'])]
```

[結果のエラー]

```
KeyError: 'CityCode'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

まだpandasに対する理解があまりできておらず、初歩的な質問で申し訳ないのですが、ぜひご教授お願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

以下、`pandas.Series.map + pandas.DataFrame.assign` と `pandas.DataFrame.merge` を使う方法を示します。

**[pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) + [pandas.DataFrame.assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)**

```
>>> df1 = df1.assign(CityId = df1.Residence.map(df2.set_index('City').CityId))
>>> df1
    Name Residence  CityId
0   John     Osaka    1001
1  Milke     Kyoto    1002
2   Saya    Nagoya    1004
3   Taro     Kyoto    1002
```

**[pandas.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)**

```
>>> df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='Residence', right_on='City', how='left').drop(columns='City')
>>> df1
    Name Residence  CityId
0   John     Osaka    1001
1  Milke     Kyoto    1002
2   Saya    Nagoya    1004
3   Taro     Kyoto    1002
```

Comment: 回答いただきありがとうございます。
試したところ、'CityId' がfloat型になってしまう場合があるのですが、改善することは可能でしょうか。